# wxPython enable panel does not work on ubuntu, does work on windows

Tags: wxpython

in the **init** of a class derived from wxFrame, I do this:

```
self.pnlGroups.Enabled = False
```

OK, the panel and all its child controls are indeed 'disabled'. 
Now, I have this code:

```
def btnNewTicketOnButtonClick( self, event ):
    self.pnlGroups.Enabled = True
```

On windows XP this works fine and all child controls get 'enabled'.
However, on Ubuntu Linux 10.4 and newer, this does not work as expected. One child control DOES get enabled but the rest of the buttons don't and I have no clue why.

Comment: Can you show us how you have your child widgets created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was my mistake, an artifact of the early days of development was disabling the individual buttons...

Puzzles me though why on windows it worked at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `self.pnlGroups.Enable()` and `self.pnlGroups.Disable()`.

Comment: Can you narrow the problem to small runnable app?